# waterline transactions on multiple models

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am using Sails waterline mysql adapter to manage My-SQL database,

I have 3 models during the supression I must execute queries in Seire, but if the last is fail I have to do a rollback . is that possible with waterline and transactions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can user Model.query function for this purpose. It lets you execute any native SQL query. For example

```
var myQuery  = "select * from users";
User.query(myQuery, function(err, result){
  if(err){
    // error handling here
  }
  else{
    // result handling here
  }
})
```

Observe the result object carefully by doing a console log.

For your case, you will need to write a SQL stored procedure for performing all your operations in a transaction. Then your code becomes

```
var myQuery = "call store_proc_name(params)";
```

Here result object will be slightly complicated to understand. Analyse it carefully. Now, word of caution when using native queries is to make sure you escape the user supplied parameters to avoid SQL injection attacks